# Ubuntu Minimal only install desktop, terminal, package manager, file manager and firefox

Tags: ubuntu-minimal

So basically I am trying to setup a minimal ubuntu installation.

I discovered this: http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/minimal

But I only need a desktop, a terminal, a packagemanager, a file manager and firefox, that's all.

I am a total newbie to Linux so I need help to set all that up.

Comment: I don't see a question that needs answering ;-) By the way: all of these are installed when you install a desktop. Ubuntu software center lets you remove other default installed software. Nothing there that is too difficult.

Comment: which desktop? openbox, gnome, kde, xfce, lxde, ...
which file manager? thunar, rox, spacefm, pcmanfm, dolphin, ?commander, ....
which packagemanager? synaptic, apt, software center ....
which terminal? rxvt, lxterminal, mrxvt, ... oh boy! too much to list :)
firefox is easy: in a terminal write & hit enter below sudo apt-get install firefox